# administracion crud

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en una Tienda Online.

En mi sistema:

- Hay varios usuarios registrados en la base de datos.
- Cada usuario agrega sus productos, sus categorías, y tiene sus propios
  clientes.
- *Al entrar al panel de administración todos ven las categorías de todos y sus productos.*

**Quiero que cada usuario solo vea sus categorías y productos.**

He buscado documentación pero no he encontrado exactamente lo que busco.

[Categorias de Todos los usuarios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR7EX.png)

Aqui les dejo el codigo que tengo solo de las categorias

```
<?php

namespace laravel\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use laravel\Http\Requests;
use laravel\Categoria;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use laravel\Http\Requests\CategoriaFormRequest;
use DB;
use Session;

class CategoriaController extends Controller
{


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request)
       {
        $query=trim($request->get('searchText'));
        $categorias=DB::table('categoria as c')
        ->join('proveedor as p','c.idProveedor','=','p.idProveedor')
        ->select('c.idCategoria','c.nombre','p.nombre as proveedor')
        ->where('c.nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
    ->where ('condicon','=','0')
        ->orderBy('idCategoria','desc')
    ->paginate (7);
        return view('almacen.categoria.index',["categorias"=>$categorias,"searchText"=>$query]);
       }
    }
    public function create ()
    {

      $proveedores=DB::table('proveedor')->get();
      return view("almacen.categoria.create",["proveedores"=>$proveedores]);
    }

    public function store(CategoriaFormRequest $request)
    {
    $categoria=new Categoria;
    $categoria->idProveedor=$request->get('idProveedor');
    $categoria->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
    $categoria->save();
    return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');
     }
     public function show($id)
     { 

        return view("almacen.categoria.show",["categoria"=>Categoria::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
    public function edit($id)
     { 
        $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
        $proveedores=DB::table('proveedor')->get();
        return view("almacen.categoria.edit",["categoria"=>$categoria,"proveedores"=>$proveedores]);
    }

    public function update(CategoriaFormRequest $request,$id)
    {

         $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
         $categoria->idProveedor=$request->get('idProveedor');
         $categoria->nombre=$request->get('nombre');
         $categoria->update();
         return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');

    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $categoria=Categoria::findOrFail($id);
        $categoria->condicon='-1';        
        $categoria->update();
    return Redirect::to('almacen/categoria');
    }
}
```

Comment: Al crear una categoría o producto, ¿estas asociando lo que creas al creador de algún modo? Si no es así, no podrás filtrar con esos criterios posteriormente, al establecer la relación solo tienes que usarla a la hora de mostrar las categorías y los productos. Saludos.

Comment: Por experiencia, te puedo decir que las `Categorías` no deben ser únicas por `Usuarios`, algunos usuarios podrían repetir `Categorías` y esto, en BD grandes te traerá problemas, solo relaciona `Usuarios` con `Productos` y en cada `Producto` relacionalo a una `Categoría`, al final solo muestras las `Categorías` que tengan tus `Productos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se haría normalmente en Laravel es definir las relaciones en los modelos, en este caso serían Usuario - Categoría - Producto, y a partir de ahí es muy sencillo obtener las categorías y productos correspondientes para cada usuario.

Para eso hay que definir los 3 modelos según la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

A continuación voy a mostrar como quedaría la parte que nos interesa de dichos modelos (las relaciones):

User

```
class User extends ...
{
    // ...

    public function categorias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Categoria::class');
    }
}
```

Categoria

```
class Categoria extends ...
{
    // ...

    public function productos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Producto::class');
    }
}
```

Se deberían definir las relaciones recíprocas también, incluyendo las del modelo Producto, pero vamos a mantenerlo simple para este caso.

Posteriormente se pueden cargar de varias maneras las categorías y productos correspondientes:

```
$query = $request->searchText;

$categorias = Categoria::where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                       ->whereUserId(auth()->user()->id)
                       ->paginate(7);
```

Para cargar las relaciones necesarias como productos o proveedores, puedes usar Eager Loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading